# Pearson coefficient of skewness vs nonparametric measure of skewness

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

I was wondering whether someone can explain the difference between [Pearson's coefficient of skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson%27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness):
$$
\mu_3=\frac{E[(X-\mu)^3]}{(E[(X - \mu)^2])^{3/2}}
$$

and its [nonparametric version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew#Definition):
$$
\mu_3=\frac{3(\text{mean - median})}{\text{standard deviation}}
$$

Probably my confusion comes from the fact that I don't see any "parameters" of $X$ in the first definition. Any reference to literature is appreciated.

Comment: In a sense they are both non-parametric, in that they can be applied to any distribution on the real numbers where the relevant statistics are finite.  They do not depend on some parameter in a family of distributions.  But since they have different definitions they will usually give different values, and in some cases different signs

Comment: That's what I thought, but I still don't understand the difference. If they both measure the same thing, what is the point of having two versions and why the second one is *emphasized* to be nonparametric?

Comment: They do not measure the same thing, just roughly similar things. If the third moment matters to you, then use the first; if it doesn't and only have summary statistics then you might use the second.  For an exponential distribution you seem to get $2$ and about $0.92$, which are rather different, and would get $1$ for the alternative $\frac{\text{mean - mode}}{\text{standard deviation}}$

Comment: @Henry I see, thanks. In my case, distribution can be multimodal so this "mode" variant of skewness won't work very well. So the main difference in that "third moment of distribution" is described by the first equation, and "just plain summary statistics" is by the second. Is that correct?